# Combobox triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have dialog which contains a combobox

```
  <ComboBox Margin="0,1,34,36" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=CompanyView}" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCompany}"
```

The itemsource is bound to a collectionviewsource and the selected item is bound to a property in my viewmodel which is non shared

```
  private Company selectedCompany;
       public Company SelectedCompany
       {

           get{ return this.selectedCompany;}
           set
           {
               this.selectedCompany = value;
               FilterString = this.selectedCompany.Id;
           }
       }
```

I can open and close the dialog as many times as i want without any problem . My problem is that
if i select a item  in the company combo and then closes the dialog, when i open the dialog again the form tries to set the SelectedCompany which in this case i null. I could check for null but i would rather understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `CollectionViewSource` tracks its own SelectedItem, and this item is probably `null`. So when it binds `ItemsSource` it is also trying to bind `SelectedItem` to the `CollectionViewSource.SelectedItem` at the same time. After that binding completes, the regular `SelectedItem` binding runs, however by this point `SelectedCompany` has been set `null`.

If this is the case, I would suggest staying away from `CollectionViewSource` and binding to a straight collection instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the collectionviewsource for filtering and sorting but it seems strange to me because im creating a new viewmodel for each time i show the dialog. It seems to me that there must be something preserved when i close the dialog.

Comment: If i use VS and break in the constructor and make objectid i can see its a new viewmodel.

Comment: @klashagelqvist Would you be able to post more of your code? Particularly the bits where your ViewModel is created, your Dialog is bound, and the initial SelectedCompany is set?

Comment: Got it to work seems like IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" is the way to go when working with CollectionView sources. I tried different solutions with different problems. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem might be that you have different instances of window/viewmodel and opening a new dialog might create a new instance of the VM which has the selectedCompany default to null. Is this your case?

Comment: No i need to create a new viewmodel and its only when i have selected a customer in the previously opened dialog that the problem occurs